# Is there an elegant way to use struct and namedtuple instead of this?

Tags: python, struct, binaryfiles, namedtuple

I'm reading a binary file made up of records that in C would look like this:

```
typedef _rec_t
{
  char text[20];
  unsigned char index[3];
} rec_t;
```

Now I'm able to parse this into a tuple with 23 distinct values, but would prefer if I could use `namedtuple` to combine the first 20 bytes into `text` and the three remaining bytes into `index`. How can I achieve that? Basically instead of one tuple of 23 values I'd prefer to have two tuples of 20 and 3 values respectively and access these using a "natural name", i.e. by means of `namedtuple`.

I am currently using the format `"20c3B"` for `struct.unpack_from()`.

Note: There are many consecutive records in the string when I call `parse_text`.

---

My code (stripped down to the relevant parts):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import struct
from collections import namedtuple

def parse_text(data):
    fmt = "20c3B"
    l = len(data)
    sz = struct.calcsize(fmt)
    num = l/sz
    if not num:
        print "ERROR: no records found."
        return
    print "Size of record %d - number %d" % (sz, num)
    #rec = namedtuple('rec', 'text index')
    empty = struct.unpack_from(fmt, data)
    # Loop through elements
    # ...

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print "ERROR: need to give file with texts as argument."
        sys.exit(1)
    s = os.path.getsize(sys.argv[1])
    f = open(sys.argv[1])
    try:
        data = f.read(s)
        parse_text(data)
    finally:
        f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `data = str()` (in `main`) is unnecessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

> Unpacked fields can be named by assigning them to variables or by wrapping the result in a named tuple:

```
>>> record = 'raymond   \x32\x12\x08\x01\x08'
>>> name, serialnum, school, gradelevel = unpack('<10sHHb', record)

>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Student = namedtuple('Student', 'name serialnum school gradelevel')
>>> Student._make(unpack('<10sHHb', record))
Student(name='raymond   ', serialnum=4658, school=264, gradelevel=8)
```

so in your case

```
>>> import struct
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> data = "1"*23
>>> fmt = "20c3B"
>>> Rec = namedtuple('Rec', 'text index') 
>>> r = Rec._make([struct.unpack_from(fmt, data)[0:20], struct.unpack_from(fmt, data)[20:]])
>>> r
Rec(text=('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), index=(49, 49, 49))
>>>
```

slicing the unpack variables maybe a problem, if the format was `fmt = "20si"` or something standard where we don't return sequential bytes, we wouldn't need to do this.

```
>>> import struct
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> data = "1"*24
>>> fmt = "20si"
>>> Rec = namedtuple('Rec', 'text index') 
>>> r = Rec._make(struct.unpack_from(fmt, data))
>>> r
Rec(text='11111111111111111111', index=825307441)
>>>
```

Comment: Aaah, see ... the creative use of slicing inside the `_make` call was what I was missing. Thanks a bunch. I was following the docs up to that point, but didn't get how to do this without extra variables. I'll accept as soon as I can, but cannot upvote until after midnight (used up all votes :)).

Comment: @0xC0000022L no problem, though it is a pain to slice because of the overhead, but giving I don't know much about your situation this the best I could come up with.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah I know but it's in the docs, and their official so I don't know ...

Comment: You can make things more elegant using `str = struct.Struct('fmt-goes-here')` to abstract the structure and then use `r = Rec._make(str.unpack(data)` to avoid the ugly call to `struct.unpack_from()`.  This also lets you use `str.size` to get the `struct.calcsize()` value for the format string.

Comment: I wonder how this would look with `dataclass` instead of `namedtuple`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my answer.  I first wrote it using slicing instead of `struct.unpack()` but @samy.vilar pointed out that we can just use the "s" format to actually get the string out.  (I should have remembered that!)

This answer uses `struct.unpack()` twice: once to get the strings out, and once to unpack the second string as an integer.

I'm not sure what you want to do with the `"3B"` item, but I'm guessing you want to unpack that as a 24-bit integer.  I appended a 0 byte on the end of the 3-char string and unpacked as an integer, in case that is what you want.

Slightly tricky: the line like `n, = struct.unpack(...)` unpacks a length-1 tuple into one variable.  In Python, the comma makes the tuple, so with one comma after one name we are using tuple unpacking to unpack a length-1 tuple into a single variable.

Also, we can use a `with` to open the file, which eliminates the need for the `try` block.  We can also just use `f.read()` to read the whole file in one go, with no need to compute the size of the file.

```
def parse_text(data):
    fmt = "20s3s"
    l = len(data)
    sz = struct.calcsize(fmt)

    if l % sz != 0:
        print("ERROR: input data not a multiple of record size")

    num_records = l / sz
    if not num_records:
        print "ERROR: zero-length input file."
        return

    ofs = 0
    while ofs < l:
        s, x = struct.unpack(fmt, data[ofs:ofs+sz])
        # x is a length-3 string; we can append a 0 byte and unpack as a 32-bit integer
        n, = struct.unpack(">I", chr(0) + x) # unpack 24-bit Big Endian int
        ofs += sz
        ... # do something with s and with n or x

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: program_name <input_file_name>")
        sys.exit(1)

    _, in_fname = sys.argv

    with open(in_fname) as f:
        data = f.read()
        parse_text(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thank you, this answer has some concepts that I read in the book (Learning Python) but haven't much used myself as of yet.

Comment: thanks again. This solution is brilliant, especially the part with decoding the integer. Thanks for that. Since my question was different (due, in part, to lack of knowledge) I think it would be unfair accept this answer. However, I actively sifted through some other Python-related answers from you and spent some of my daily vote quota. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Why not have parse_text use string slicing (data[:20], data[20:]) to pull apart the two values, and then process each one with struct?

Or take the 23 values and slice them apart into two?

I must be missing something.  Perhaps you wish to make this happen via the struct module?

Comment: +1.  The string data is right there in `data` and it is trivial to use slicing to get out the two fixed-length strings; there is no need to use `struct.unpack_from()` to get strings out of a string.  `struct` is hugely valuable to unpack integer and float values, but here we just have strings.

Comment: @steveha: I don't need `unpack_from` even though I want to use the `offset`? Remember this is an example I shrunk down.

Comment: @user1277476: the string contains `num` records (see the code). That's why I was using `unpack_from` in the first place. Of course slicing would also work. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you can also use `struct` if you just use `"20s"` instead of `"20c"`.  Then you get a length-20 string.  Might as well do that instead of slicing.  I posted an answer but I will edit it to do this.